# Is it possible to use the static type of an object on call site as an automatically deduced template argument to its template method?

Tags: c++, templates

Template methods allows to span a set of method instances for different static type of arguments. Automatic argument deduction avoids duplication of information.

We are faced with a situation in which the static type we would like to automatically deduce as a template argument is the type of the class instance itself. (On the call site, the type of the instance can be a more specialised type than the class in which the template method is declared.)

eg.

```
class Base
{
public:
    template <class T_callingObject>
    T_callingObject foo()
    {
        bar += 1;
        // We have a strong guarantee on this cast only if T_callingObject
        // is automatically deduced !
        return static_cast<T_callingObject&>(*this);
    }

private:
    int bar;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};

int main()
{
    Base base;
    Derived derived;

    base = base.foo<Base>();           // we already know the type of base is Base
    derived = derived.foo<Derived>();  // idem
}
```

The question is : Is there a way not to repeat the type of `base` and `derived` ?

**Edit**: CRTP on `Base` is not an option here, we need to have a common ancestor type.

Comment: bar is uninitialized here, just FYI. And you might have another base class and the CRTP as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is generally addressed with CRTP (Curiously Recursive Template Pattern) by making `Base` a template itself:

```
template <typename D>
struct Base {
    D& foo() { return static_cast<D&>(*this); }
};
```

and thus `struct Derived: Base<Derived>`.

The set of operations you can conduct on the `D` parameters is restricted (it is an incomplete time at the time `Base<Derived>` is instantiated), but in your simple case this works.

You are still left to wonder if someone will not inadvertently write `struct Bar: Base<Foo>` though, so this only *reduces* the problematic surface.

**EDIT**: if CRTP for `Base` is not allowed (which often happen), you can layer the abstractions:

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base() {} };

template <typename D>
struct BaseT: Base {
    D& foo() { return static_cast<D&>(*this); }
};

struct Derived: BaseT<Derived> {};
```

Since in general if `foo` needs to know what `D` is, you no longer have a single unified type.

Comment: Exactly what I suggested: have a base class (the common ancestor OP was talking about) and the CRTP on the first derived.

Comment: @MarcoA.: Yes, it's really the typical approach to the issue :)